# return all row where mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have this tables:

```html
tbl_1
+---+--------+
|ID | NAME   |
+---+--------+
| 1 | Name_1 |
| 2 | Name_2 |
| 3 | Name_3 |
+---+--------+

tbl_2
+---+----------+---------+
|ID | MENTIUNI | ID_NAME |
+---+----------+---------+
| 1 | abc      |   1     |
| 2 | abcd     |   2     |
| 3 | abc      |   1     |
| 4 | abcd     |   1     |
| 5 | abc      |   2     |
| 6 | abcd     |   3     |
+---+----------+---------+

SELECT
 tbl_1.NAME,
 count(tbl_2.MENTIUNI) AS NR_MENTIUNI

FROM tbl_1

LEFT JOIN tbl_2 ON tbl_1
 tbl_1.ID = tbl_2.ID_NAME

WHERE tbl_2.MENTIUNI = 'abc'
```

Query-ul de mai sus imi selecteaza din tbl_1.ID, numai cele care se regasesc in tbl_2 sub conditia tbl_2.MENTIUNI = 'abc'

Cum pot afisa toate id-urile din tbl_1 chiar daca am conditie in where ?

The above query selects me from tbl_1.ID, only those found in tbl_2 under the condition tbl_2.MENTIUNI = 'abc'

How can I display all ids in tbl_1 even if I have a condition in where?

```html
+------+-------------+
| NAME | NR_MENTIUNI |
+------+-------------+
|Name_1|      2      |
|Name_2|      1      |
|Name_3|      0      |
+------+-------------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please try to use English fully.

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition from the entire query to just the `JOIN` clause, so it only filters the records in the second table being joined.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    tbl_1.NAME,
    count(tbl_2.MENTIUNI) AS NR_MENTIUNI
FROM tbl_1
    LEFT JOIN tbl_2
        ON tbl_1.ID = tbl_2.ID_NAME
        AND tbl_2.MENTIUNI = 'abc'
```

Comment: Please use `group by` clause whenever you use an aggegate function. MySQL doesn't require it, but a large number of database system will return an error without it. 
But i approve the answer, well done :)